# Javascript callbacks, refering to own object

Tags: javascript, callback

Below is a very simplified version of my problem. Without changing the definition of object "o" and without using the name "obj", how can i refer to obj inside foo.

```
var obj = {
    foo: function () {
        alert(this.greet); // => undefined, obj.greet works but not feasible for my case
    },
    greet: "hi"
};

var o = {
    m: obj.foo
};

o.m();
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a new function that calls the old function with the correct context. [The `bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will do this for you in sufficiently modern browsers.

```
var o = {
    m: obj.foo.bind(obj)
};
```

If you want to support legacy browsers:

```
var o = {
    m: (function (context) { 
        return function () { 
            context.foo(); 
        };
    }(obj))
};
```

Comment: For older browsers, there is a full `.bind()` polyfill on the MDN page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or could not change the definition of the object `o`, you can do the following:

Instead of

```
o.m();
```

do

```
o.m.call(obj);
```